# How did this user format this comment in this way?

Tags: support

<sup>this is really a very inconsequential question, I'm just curious.</sup>

[This is a comment on KOTH: A world wide pandemic:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70135/koth-a-world-wide-pandemic#comment171677_70135)

[image]

At least to my browser's rendering engine, there's a fairly clear difference between the <s>struckthrough text</s> and the other text: both font style and font size.

[image]

As we can see, the comment's HTML attributes and CSS classes are identical to the one immediately preceding it.

What's going on here, and how can I post comments in fancy fonts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [special Unicode characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Unicode).

> The “combining long stroke overlay” (U+0336) results in an unbroken stroke across the text

Incidentally, please don't do that. They show up absolutely horribly from my phone (from which I am posting this answer)...

[image]

... for a very questionable benefit.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. I don't know why the poster decided to use such a character because last I checked, <s>strikethrough</s> works in comments, but perhaps not

Comment: Clearly, not. :)

Comment: @cat Comments are mini-markdown -- no HTML.

Comment: On my phone (via the app), it just renders the characters without the strikethrough.

Comment: And on Chrome for Android, using both mobile and desktop view.